# undefined method `author' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I have some problems with my rails application.

```
<% @story.chapters.each do |chapter| %>
    <% if round.to_s != chapter.round %> 
        <% if chosenChapterRound != chapter.round %>
            <% maxVotes = 0 %>
        <% end %>
        <% if chapter.votes.count > maxVotes %>
            <% maxVotes = chapter.votes.count %>
            <% chosenChapterRound = chapter.round %>
            <% chosenChapters[round.to_i] = chapter %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
<% chosenChapters.each do |chosenChapter| %>
    <%= chosenChapter %>
<% end %>
```

this outputs something like this: #< Chapter:0x007fa1b8f59888>

What I really want to do is this:

```
<% chosenChapters.each do |chosenChapter| %>
    <%= chosenChapter.author %>
<% end %>
```

But whenever I try to access one of the attributes inside of chosenChapter, I get a the following errormessage:

```
undefined method `author' for nil:NilClass
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least one of your `chosenChapters` is `nil`. The problem is probably in the following fragment:

```
<% maxVotes = chapter.votes.count %>
<% chosenChapterRound = chapter.round %>
<% chosenChapters[round.to_i] = chapter %>
```

Comment: Thanks! It was exactly as you said.